# denormal exception in gdb debugger for gfortran

Tags: gfortran

I'm compiling with gfortran including the compiler options
-g -fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow,underflow,denormal
This has lead to an executable that runs under the gdb debugger, but when running normally a floating point exception occurs.  The latter disappears if I recompile without the denormal trap.

Could it be that the denormal trap does not work when running with gdb?

Any suggestions on how to find where the floating point exception occurs?

Comment: When running normally and a floating point exception occurs, does it drop a core file?  You should be able to do `gdb ./exe exe.core` and get the line number.  Here `exe` is your executable program.

Comment: My executable file name is tst08.exe, so I tried your command line replacing both occurrences of "exe" by "tst08.exe".  This yields "No such file or directory".  Did I misinterpret your recommendation?

Comment: Probably not.  I'm guessing your using gfortran on WIndows.  I am familiar with how gfortran and gdb work on Unix-like operating systems.  Perhaps, Windows does not support subnormal number or dropping core.

Answer (score 0):

By running a simple test it appeared that that denormal trap remained active both under normal and fdb execution even only the underflow trap and not denormal trap was included in the compilation.

The problem was finally traced back to uninitialized variables, which reasonably might take on different different values with gdb or normal execution.  To localize the problem without the debugger, I used not only many debugging write statements, but also stop statements moved sequentially further back until the error was localized, for it appears that the code races ahead of the write statements, and a later fpe may cause a write statement not to be executed even if it occurs before the fpe.

Somehow the -Wuninitialized  compiler option had not detected the use of uninitialized variables.

These experiences are indeed from a windows installation of gfortran and the associated fdb debugger, that dates back to around 2016.

Comment: Yep, -Wuninitilized might miss a variable.  This typically happens with a variable is inside some deeply nested if-endif and/or do-loop constructs.  It may help with debugging to use the -finit-real=NAN option.  This will initialize all otherwise unitialized variable to NaN.